# Elaboration on "display: none;" and content loading

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find solid answers on the effects of "display: none;" and content loading.

I've long been under the impression some browsers wont load external resources within content that has a style of "display: none", does this still vary cross-platform?

Furthermore, does this vary with mobile platforms?

Generally, I use a mixture of opacity, filters (IE), height/width, and absolute positioning to assure that my content will be loaded but not visible.  Is this still necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this site by Tim Kadlec (with credits to the Cloud Four team) helps you a little bit further:
http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

Greetings,
Gunther

Comment: Upvoting because that is awesome and somewhat related - sadly it still doesn't answer the original question.  Still, thank you - I very much appreciate this response. :)

Answer (score -1):

In most modern browswers, simply using display:none should suffice.  There may be rare cases that you have to do a little more digging into, but for the most part you should see full functionality.  I haven't had to use the abs positioning hack (moving the content out of the viewable region(s)) in quite some time, as display:none seems to do the trick.

As far as cross-platform, browsers are getting better at rendering CSS consistently.  From my experience, display:none seems to function perfectly across most modern browsers.  Older browsers could still have issues to work-around.

I have not had a lot of experience in mobile, so I will refrain from offering any opinion or guess.

Using filters, h/w, abs pos is no longer a necessary evil , as "display:none" will allow you to just hide the container where it is naturally positioned, instead of moving/hiding here and then re-positioning when loaded.

Comment: This answer has absolutely no basis and no explanation as to why I can "get away with" these methods.

Comment: Also, jQuery functions are a horrible suggestion over using CSS.

Comment: @ShawnKhameneh Firstly, You asked "Generally, I use a mixture of opacity, filters (IE), height/width, and absolute positioning to assure that my content will be loaded but not visible. Is this still necessary?".  Necessary?  No. Secondly, the jQuery over CSS is a matter of personal opinion, unless you can provide something that solidifies that...  Thanks!

Comment: Lose scripting over tight CSS is generally bad practice unless you can justify using scripting.  jQuery is a tool for scripting, not a crutch for not properly implementing CSS declarations.  You can get away with this, but when used repeatedly in large applications it has an impact and very much hurts performance.  Just because you can do something doesn't make it right.  Do you need more reasons?  I can make a whole list with strict use scenarios.

Comment: Also, jQuery hide() is essentially "display: none" - my question was what are the cross-platform impacts and what is optimal for cross-platform.  Not what I can get away with nor why I should (or shouldn't) be using jQuery.

Comment: I was under the following assumption: since you are hiding content until it loads (not clear if and when it is displayed), you would be then displaying the content via some form of scripting.  I just figured since you may have been using javascript to show the element, via adding/remove class, modifying css, etc, that it would be just as easy to utilize the show/hide.  As far as cross-platform is concerned - most modern browsers should function perfectly with display:none.  If you plan to support earlier browsers - you will more than likely have to include the abs positioning, opacity, etc.